# Append element to second presence of a HTML class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append an element to another element. Problem is that the 'target element' is only identified by a class and this class is used twice. **In my case i want to append to the last/second presence of the element.** Check fiddle here for a visualization

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kodz/1a14g4hu/3/)

**Start point:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myClass">This is a <strong>not</strong> the target</div>
    <div class="myClass">This is the target</div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <div class="source">This is the source</div>
</div>
```

**Goal**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myClass">This is a <strong>not</strong> the target</div>
    <div class="myClass">This is the target
          <div class="source">This is the source</div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <!-- Big beautiful hole of emptiness -->
</div>
```

**What I tried**

```
$(".source").appendTo(".myClass");
```

Which appends ".source" to both divs with the class ".myClass".

Comment: You can use $(".container div").eq(0).append(".myClass")

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to `append to` or `insert after`???  Or you made just a mistake in your expected HTML markup?

Comment: Please, do not add "Solved" to the title of the question. Just accept the correct answer. Refer to this article, please: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Question solved. Thanks guys. Can't be that unclear since I was provided with an answer within 1 min. Alternative solutions are always welcome. Will however edit the 'goal' html so its correct according to appendTo

Comment: Well can't accept an answer yet but the answer was provided. Will accept when timelimit on it is done. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:last` selector:

```
$(".source").appendTo(".myClass:last");
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1a14g4hu/5/)

Comment: Or `$(".source").appendTo(".myClass:nth-of-type(2)");` for the second.

Answer (score 3):

According to your **goal**, you want to place your item **after** the last of `myClass`, not **inside of it**.

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="myClass">This is a <strong>not</strong> the target</div>
   <div class="myClass">This is the target</div>
   <div class="source">This is the source</div>
 </div>
```

However, `appendTo` adds the current item as **the last child** of another item. You can use the approach, described by other answerers, if you actually need the following result:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="myClass">This is a <strong>not</strong> the target</div>
   <div class="myClass">
     This is the target
     <div class="source">This is the source</div>
   </div>       
 </div>
```

In order to place element after another one, like in your **goal**, use `insertAfter`:

```
$(".source").insertAfter(".myClass:last");
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/1a14g4hu/6/) out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/),

```
$(".source").appendTo(".myClass:last");
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/1a14g4hu/4/)